# Seeking Angular.js compatible grid with column filtering of undisplayed data

Tags: angularjs, gridview

Can you **suggest a grid** to use in an **Angular.js** application that supports filtering based on a list of values not necessarily contained within the visible data-set.

For example...

- There is a large collection of data describing cars with color property.
- There are 20 available colors.
- Only five records out of 1000 are loaded.
- The grid should have a column filter that will display all of the available colors and not simply those colors present in the five records returned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering) supports what I'm looking for.